# get the facebook access token in iOS 6.0

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

I had implemented facebook SDK with the help of which able to get the facebook authentication as well as user info with the following code.

```
  if(!self.accountStore)
    self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
if(NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") != nil)
{
    ACAccountType *facebookTypeAccount = [self.accountStore 
    accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:@"com.apple.facebook"];
    NSLog(@"facebookTypeAccount..:%@",facebookTypeAccount);
    NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookTypeAccount];

    if (facebookTypeAccount) {
        if ([accounts respondsToSelector:@selector(count)]) {
            [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookTypeAccount
                                                       options:@{ACFacebookAppIdKey:  
                                     @"key", ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email"]}
                                                    completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError 
                                                                             *error) {
              if(granted){
            NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore 
                                       accountsWithAccountType:facebookTypeAccount];
                        [self fetchuserinfo];

                                                            }

                                                    }];

        }



        -(void)fetchuserinfo
         {
        NSString *accessToken = [FBSession activeSession].accessToken;
       NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];
        NSURL *meurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
       SLRequest *merequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                          requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                    URL:meurl
                                             parameters:nil];

NSLog(@" setting account %@",_facebookAccount);

merequest.account = _facebookAccount;

[merequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    NSString *meDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    returnedData = responseData;

    NSLog(@" meRequest Respnse %@", meDataString);
    if (returnedData!=nil) {
        if(NSClassFromString(@"NSJSONSerialization"))
        {
            NSError *error = nil;
            id object = [NSJSONSerialization
                         JSONObjectWithData:returnedData
                         options:0
                         error:&error];

            if(error) {  }


            if([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
            {
                NSDictionary *results = object;

                NSString *categoryString=[[results valueForKeyPath:@"picture.data"] objectForKey:@"url"];

                NSString *userid=[results objectForKey:@"id"];
                if (userid != nil)
                {
                    self.gotUserDetails = YES;
                }
                NSString *username=[results objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSString *email=[results objectForKey:@"email"];

               NSUserDefaults *userId=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [userId setObject:userid forKey:@"userid"];


            }

        }
    }
    }
```

But to post the feed (https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed/access_token=) from this login user I need access token. If anyone know how to get the access token in iOS 6.0 please help me.

Thanks to all.

Comment: I have done it using Sharekit.If that can help you here is link to my blog for the same.http://amandeepsinghmaan.blogspot.in/2012/08/get-fb-access-token-from-share-kit-to.html

Comment: No @DesertRose I need to get in iOS 6.0 via facebook SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than worrying about getting the token and passing that with you call, Apple have provided `SLRequest` which you can use. You specify the target URL and parameters and `SLRequest` deals (transparently) with the authentication, transmission and collection of the response data.

---

You may not actually get the token, but you still need to get authorisation and that authorisation is linked to the list of things you want to do. Your code currently just shows that you want to get the e-mail address, but you can add other permissions:

```
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType
                                          options:
     @{
                              ACFacebookAppIdKey : ...,
                        ACFacebookPermissionsKey : @[ @"email", @"read_stream", @"user_groups", @"user_videos" ]),
     }
                                       completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) { ...
```

You need to check the Facebook documentation to find out what permissions you need to request from the user and fill them in for `ACFacebookPermissionsKey`.

Comment: And you're calling that code after getting the appropriate permission using the top code in your question? (I expect more than just email permission is required).

Comment: will u provide me some example

Comment: its working properly when I try to post the feed after login. But I need to post the feed in some other controller after login.

Comment: its working properly with only email permission key but I unable to post the feed in some other controller.

Comment: posting updates to the feed requires different permissions. The Facebook documentation details what permissions you need to request for each call you want to make...

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try This

-(void)fetchuserinfo
{
    NSString *accessToken = [FBSession activeSession].accessToken;
    NSLog(@"%@",accessToken);
}

or

-(void)fetchuserinfo
{
    NSLog(@"%@",FBSession.activeSession.accessToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

facebook SDK 3.2 in iOS 7 & iOS 8 , it works fine for me.

You should import FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
....
[self checkFBIDWithToken:[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken];
```

PS:"checkFBIDWithToken:(NSString *)tempToken" is a method.

facebook doc: [accessToken](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)